# How to get toolbar separator in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

[image]

I would like to get the separator in SwiftUI, but I didn't find the way. This was screenshot from mail.app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your view elements are in a `HStack` (like your mail.app suggest) using `Divider()` will give you a vertical "separator".

Elsewhere `Divider()` will give you a horizontal "separator".

You can adjust its size, like this: `Divider().frame(width: 123)`

You can of course do more things with Dividers, such as set its thickness or height with different color:

```
HStack {
    Divider().frame(width: 5, height: 50).background(Color.blue)
    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle")
    Divider().frame(width: 10, height: 100).background(Color.pink)
    Image(systemName: "envelope")
    Divider().frame(width: 15, height: 150).background(Color.green)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way of doing such thing, do not use Divider, because it has lots of issues. With Divider you cannot control the thickness, also it has issue with updating color, wired Xcode complain in console in some cases, also space issue, it takes more space than it needs. In general it does not worth to use it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            Group {
                
                Image(systemName: "mail")
                
                Capsule().fill(Color.secondary).frame(width: 2.0)
                
                Image(systemName: "trash")
  
            }
            .frame(width: 25, height: 25)

        }
       
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One alternative solution that may be more useful in some cases (e.g if you want a customisable toolbar the accepted solution won't work):

```
ToolbarItem (placement: .primaryAction) {
    HStack {
        Divider()
    }
}
```